# Ubuntu 16.04 installed alongside 14.04 - how can I choose which one to boot?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, 16.04

I chose to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside 14.04 during the installation. My computer automatically boots 16.04. How can I select to boot 14.04?

This is the output from `sudo update-grub`

[image: grub]

It doesn't see 14.04. What are these items it found ?

Comment: Give a try to [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Comment: Are you asking to make the default *14.04*? Or are you asking to add it to the boot menu?

Comment: Also, when your computer boots up, you should see a GRUB menu similar to [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=grub2+menuentry+examples&safe=active&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=989&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXvfykh9vRAhXFs48KHVVLBrUQ_AUIBigB#safe=active&tbm=isch&q=grub2+menu&imgrc=1-dVpIzTR_1IbM%3A). You should see something like Ubuntu 14.04 below it. Try booting into your 16.o4 and running `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: You might be better off running 14.04 in [Virtual Box](http://www.virtualbox.org)

Comment: before the grub (first boot page with color *dark aubergine*)  came up, press **Etc** to see select OS page.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ideas. When you see a screen like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj1o3.png), try using your keyboard to move down to the Ubuntu 14.04 entry. If you see only one entry and that boots to 16.04, get into 16.04, open Terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T, then type `sudo update-grub` and enter your password. It should show some output like [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/650x286xsudo-update-grub.png.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.AzzEYubOKD.png), with something like this if it sees your 14.04

`Found Ubuntu 14.04 on /dev/sdXX`

If you don't see a boot menu at all, then you may need to unhide your GRUB menu. Try pressing Shift while your computer is booting, you would see the aformentioned boot screen. For some permanent changes, follow instructions in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time) question. Good luck and please report back!

Comment: hi I posted a picture of my `sudo update grub` in my original post, it doesn't see 14.04. Are you suggesting now to press shift while my computer is booting? - Noting happens when I try this it just boots to 16.04. Thanks

Comment: @riverrock Apparently you installed the different Ubuntu releases is different modes - 16.04 in UEFI mode, 14.04 in Legacy/CSM -. As such, when booting in UEFI mode (as you should) it can only detect other OSes installed the same way. If you change the UEFI settings to Legacy/CSM you may be able to boot 14.04 but you won't see 16.04.

Comment: @riverrock then I'm not sure. Your PC is a Z87, which makes me suspect it is UEFI. Do what CelticWarrior says, and also, why both 14,04 and 16.04?

Comment: @spark, thank you, I will try that. The only reason why  choose to install it alongside was that I had programs that were Dependant on 14.04. Interesting I didn't see any options for installing in UEFI or CSM mode during the install - it just asked me do I want to install 16.04 along  side 14.04 and I said yes.